# Automatic pushing created / deleted VLANs form a Linux Router to switches

Tags: linux

I have 50 switches (HP ProCurve 2910g and Ubiquiti EdgeSwitch) and 1 Linux router.

Is there a way that I can configure a bunch of VLANs on a Linux router and push those VLAN's down to a switches using GVRP/MVRP ??

In simple words:

- Create / Delete VLANs on a Linux router
- The created / delete VLAN config get's automatic pushed down to the switches so that VLAN will be created / deleted on the switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On the Linux router|**

Enable the "GVRP" setting in VLAN interface ifconfig config file:

```
GVRP=YES
```

Bring you're interface up and down.

**On you're switch:**

Enable incoming GVRP data on the port that is connected with you're Linux router.

Comment: What is "ifconfig config file"?

Comment: @raspi What Linux-distro do you use?